# Handlebars populate data according to selected item on drop down

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I want to populate data acording to selected value on "Select" on handlebars.

My code(form) :

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <label class="form-control-label" for="form-select">User</label>
                                <select class="form-select" aria-label="Default select example">
                                    {{#each users}}
                                        <option value="{{_id}}">{{_id}} - {{name}}</option>
                                    {{/each}}
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-lg-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="form-control-label" for="input-email">{{selectedUser _id}}</label>
                                    <input type="email" id="input-email" class="form-control"
                                        placeholder="jesse@example.com" value="">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
```

I want to load the user's email after selecting the ID from the top select menu.

I created handlebar helper :

```
selectedUser: (option) => {
    return User.findOne({ _id: option });
  },
```

I want to send the selected ID to that helper.

Comment: It looks like you are mixing client-side and server-side concerns. You won't be able to have an event on the client-side - like a change to the value of a select menu - trigger a call to the database, which must be done from the server. You would either need all of the user data to be loaded with your page or to make an asynchronous request to your server each time the select value changes.